# How to check the email address is live?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email-validation

How can i check the email address live using ruby on rails?

Is there any gem ir plugins?

anything that I can find the email address is live.

Comment: did you check https://github.com/kamilc/email_verifier gem?

Comment: i am a web designer, so dont know much about backend code. But for your question i think  there is something .  Check it                         "  gmail-smtp-in " .

Answer (score 1):

Check out this  [`Email validator based on DNS`](https://gist.github.com/brianjlandau/da0bab27dcf1d8691f6e) integrated in `ActiveModel::Validator` that's means you can use it in `Rails` app:

```
require 'resolv'

class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if Resolv::DNS.new.getresources(value.split("@").last, Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::MX).empty?
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] ||  "does not have a valid domain")
    end
  rescue Resolv::ResolvError, Resolv::ResolvTimeout
    record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] ||  "does not have a valid domain")
  end
end
```

[`And this code i use in my sent email script`](https://gist.github.com/fishbullet/8586912):

```
require 'resolv'

module MailMachine
  class Validator
    def initialize(name)
      @name = name.split('@').last
    end

    def servers_list
      Resolv::DNS.open.getresources(@name, Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::MX).map do |resolv|
        resolv.exchange.to_s
      end    
    end

    def server
      servers_list.find do |name|
        Resolv.getaddress(name) =~ Resolv::AddressRegex
      end
    rescue Resolv::ResolvError => e
      #holly molyy
      return false if e.is_a? Exception
    end
  end
end
```